# Android: Why can't I see ListView items who fetch from the website?

Tags: android, listview, jsoup

I wrote this Java code for `Android`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private static final String WEBSITE_URL = "http://www.anywebsite.com/forum/";

  private ListView _lvForums;
  private ForumAdapter _forumAdapter;
  private List<ForumContent> _forumContents;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //_lvForums = findViewById(R.id.lvForums);
    _lvForums = new ListView(this);
    _lvForums.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    _forumContents = new ArrayList<>();
    setContentView(_lvForums);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Document doc = Jsoup.connect(WEBSITE_URL).get();
          //MainActivity.this.getActionBar().setTitle(doc.title());

          Elements forumContents = doc.select("div.forum_content.forum_forum");
          for (Element forum : forumContents) {
            String forumName = forum.select("span.name > a").text();
            String link = forum.select("span.name > a").attr("abs:href");
            String threadCount = forum.select("td.threadcount").text();
            String postCount = forum.select("td.postcount").text();

            Element lastPost = forum.select("td.lastpost").first();
            Element linkElement = lastPost.getElementsByTag("a").first();

            String lastPostText = lastPost.childNode(0).toString();
            String lastPostLink = linkElement.attr("abs:href");

            _forumContents.add(new ForumContent(
                forumName, link, threadCount, postCount, lastPostText, lastPostLink));
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }).start();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        _forumAdapter = new ForumAdapter(MainActivity.this, _forumContents);
        _lvForums.setAdapter(_forumAdapter);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I run the app on `Android`, I see an empty white screen but I can't see `ListView` items. I'm pretty sure that `ForumAdapter` and `ForumContent` are working so good. Because if I try like this, I can see `ListView` items:

```
_forumContents.add(new ForumContent("Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4", "Data5", "Data6"));
```

And I'm pretty sure that my `JSoup` codes, because I can get same datas with same code on Java console app.
What is the problem? How can I see `ListView` items who fetched data from the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what you're doing is, you're scraping your content in a new thread. But you're already immediately creating your Adapter in your main thread. So, basically your adapter has already been set, but your app is still busy scraping in the background.

You can make your rows "visible" by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.